# Efficiently find a given subsequence in a string, maximizing the number of contiguous characters

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, string-matching, fuzzy-search

### Long problem description

Fuzzy string matcher utilities like [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/) or [CtrlP](https://github.com/ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim) filter a list of strings for ones which have a given search string as a subsequence.
As an example, consider that a user wants to search for a specific photo in a list of files. To find the file

```
/home/user/photos/2016/pyongyang_photo1.png
```

it suffices to type `ph2016png`, because this search string is a subsequence of this file name. (Mind that this is not LCS. The whole search string must be a subsequence of the file name.)

It is trivial to check whether a given search string is a subsequence of another string, but I wonder how to efficiently obtain the *best* match: In the above example, there are multiple possible matches. One is

```
/home/user/photos/2016/pyongyang_photo1.png
```

but the one which the user probably had in mind is

```
/home/user/photos/2016/pyongyang_photo1.png
```

To formalize this, I'd define the "best" match as the one that is composed of the the smallest number of substrings. This number is 5 for the first example match and 3 for the second.

I came up with this because it would be interesting to obtain the best match to assign a score to each result, for sorting. I'm not interested in approximate solutions though, my interest in this problem is primarily of academic nature.

### tl;dr problem description

Given strings `s` and `t`, find among the  subsequences of `t` that are equal to `s` one that maximizes the number of  pairs of elements that are contiguous in `t`.

### What I've tried so far

For discussion, let's call the search query `s` and the string to test `t`. The problem's solution is denoted `fuzzy(s, t)`. I'll utilize Python's string slicing notation. The easiest approach is as follows:

Since any solution must use all characters from `s` in order, an algorithm for solving this problem can start by searching the first occurrence of `s[0]` in `t` (with index `i`) and then use the better of the two solutions

```
t[:i+1] + fuzzy(s[1:], t[i+1:])    # Use the character
t[:i]   + fuzzy(s,     t[i+1:])    # Skip it and use the next occurence 
                                   # of s[0] in t instead
```

This is obviously not the best solution to this problem. En contraire, it's the obvious brute force one. (I've played around with simultaneously searching for the last occurrence of `s[-1]` and using this information in an earlier version of this question, but it turned out that this approach does not work.)

→ My question is: What is the most efficient solution to this problem?

Comment: Nice one!!! Some clarifications: (1) You stated that the best match is the one that has the least number of _parts_. Does it mean that **all characters of the input _MUST_ be found and in the correct order?** (2) What if there are several possible matches within the same string, all with the same number of parts? Would it be of interest the **distance** between the parts?

Comment: All characters of the input must be found in the correct order. If there are several possible matches maximizing the constraint, then it suffices to return one of them.

Comment: The second part means that it is not enough to find the first match, but the whole string MUST be scanned to verify that there are no (better) matches, right?

Comment: Yes, unless there is a way to prove that there can be no better matches. For example, if I searched for `photo` in the case I outlined above, then the entire query is contained in the file name as a single substring - there obviously cannot be a better match than that.

Comment: For 2 strings of lengths n and m, this can be solved exactly in O(nm) time and space using Gotoh's algorithm for aligning 2 strings with gap-open costs.  All you need to do is specify a nonzero gap-open cost, and forbid deletions (or equivalently, assign deletions a huge penalty).

Comment: @j_random_hacker Thanks, it's good to have a name of an algorithm and terminology for the problem description! I thought about sequence alignment algorithms, but did not know that ones with adjustable penalties exist. [At first sight though, it seems that while asymptotically good, this is effectively *slower* in practice than both other solutions suggested so far.](https://repl.it/DYKl/2). (repl.it doesn't have numpy, and matrix processing in plain Python is horrendously slow, hence the large speed difference; the numpy implementation is still about 10x slower than the others.)

Comment: Perhaps, it is not enough to have the full word (`photo` in your example) found. What if it appears more than once? Should there be some kind of rating about the location? What about `Ihaveaphoblato_and_another_phblablaoto`? Or `Ihaveaphoblablablato_and_another_phblablablaoto`? I think that before trying to design an algorithm, you may need to define all the **rulers** for scoring possible conditions.

Comment: @FDavidov The location does not matter, nor do the distances between groups of substrings. `Ihavea PHO bla TO _and_another_phblablaoto`, `Ihavea PHO blato_and_another_phblablao TO` and `Ihaveaphoblablablato_and_another_ PH blablabla OTO` are all matches with a score of 2, because they consist of 2 groups of substrings each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest creating a search tree, where each node represents a character position in the haystack that matches one of the needle characters.

The top nodes are siblings and represent the occurrences of the first needle character in the haystack.

The children of a parent node are those nodes that represent the occurrences of the next needle character in the haystack, but only those that are positioned after the position represented by that parent node.

This logically means that some children are shared by several parents, and so this structure is not really a tree, but a directed acyclic graph. Some sibling parents might even have exactly the same children. Other parents might not have children at all: they are a dead-end, unless they are at the bottom of the graph where the leaves represent positions of the last needle character.

Once this graph is set up, a depth-first search in it can easily derive the number of segments that are still needed from a certain node onwards, and then minimise that among alternatives.

I have added some comments in the Python code below. This code might still be improved, but it seems already quite efficient compared to your solution.

```py
def fuzzy_trincot(haystack, needle, returnSegments = False):
    inf = float('inf')

    def getSolutionAt(node, depth, optimalCount = 2):
        if not depth: # reached end of needle
            node['count'] = 0
            return
        minCount = inf # infinity ensures also that incomplete branches are pruned
        child = node['child']
        i = node['i']+1
        # Optimisation: optimalCount gives the theoretical minimum number of  
        # segments needed for any solution. If we find such case, 
        # there is no need to continue the search.
        while child and minCount > optimalCount:
            # If this node was already evaluated, don't lose time recursing again.
            # It works without this condition, but that is less optimal.
            if 'count' not in child:
                getSolutionAt(child, depth-1, 1)
            count = child['count'] + (i < child['i'])
            if count < minCount:
                minCount = count
            child = child['sibling']
        # Store the results we found in this node, so if ever we come here again,
        # we don't need to recurse the same sub-tree again.
        node['count'] = minCount

    # Preprocessing: build tree
    # A node represents a needle character occurrence in the haystack.
    # A node can have these keys:
    #   i:       index in haystack where needle character occurs
    #   child:   node that represents a match, at the right of this index, 
    #            for the next needle character
    #   sibling: node that represents the next match for this needle character
    #   count:   the least number of additional segments needed for matching the 
    #            remaining needle characters (only; so not counting the segments
    #            already taken at the left)
    root = { 'i': -2, 'child': None, 'sibling': None }
    # Take a short-cut for when needle is a substring of haystack
    if haystack.find(needle) != -1:
        root['count'] = 1
    else:
        parent = root
        leftMostIndex = 0
        rightMostIndex = len(haystack)-len(needle)
        for j, c in enumerate(needle):
            sibling = None
            child = None
            # Use of leftMostIndex is an optimisation; it works without this argument
            i = haystack.find(c, leftMostIndex)
            # Use of rightMostIndex is an optimisation; it works without this test
            while 0 <= i <= rightMostIndex:
                node = { 'i': i, 'child': None, 'sibling': None }
                while parent and parent['i'] < i:
                    parent['child'] = node
                    parent = parent['sibling']
                if sibling: # not first child
                    sibling['sibling'] = node
                else: # first child
                    child = node
                    leftMostIndex = i+1
                sibling = node
                i = haystack.find(c, i+1)
            if not child: return False
            parent = child
            rightMostIndex += 1
        getSolutionAt(root, len(needle))

    count = root['count']
    if not returnSegments:
        return count

    # Use the `returnSegments` option when you need the character content 
    # of the segments instead of only the count. It runs in linear time.

    if count == 1: # Deal with short-cut case 
        return [needle]
    segments = []
    node = root['child']
    i = -2
    start = 0
    for end, c in enumerate(needle):
        i += 1
        # Find best child among siblings
        while (node['count'] > count - (i < node['i'])):
            node = node['sibling']
        if count > node['count']:
            count = node['count']
            if end:
                segments.append(needle[start:end])
                start = end
        i = node['i']
        node = node['child']
    segments.append(needle[start:])
    return segments
```

The function can be called with an optional third argument:

```
haystack = "/home/user/photos/2016/pyongyang_photo1.png"
needle = "ph2016png"

print (fuzzy_trincot(haystack, needle))

print (fuzzy_trincot(haystack, needle, True))
```

Outputs:

```
3
['ph', '2016', 'png']
```

As the function is optimised to return only the count, the second call will add a bit to the execution time.

Comment: On first sight, this solution sounds related to Gotoh's algorithm suggested in the comments above, and it also looks as if it is has the same asymptotic behavior. (It should be better in practice, because the tree is of size n*m only in special cases). It is much easier to understand though. Also, at least in this implementation, it is indeed quite fast! In practice, this is [about on par with Nelxiost's solution](https://repl.it/DYKl/7), often even a little faster - except in cases like `haystack = "a"*50, needle = "a"*50`, for obvious reasons. Great!

Comment: Thanks. I like this question! I am looking at some random strings, and just want to mention that `fuzzy_pberndt` fails for test case `("abbcabaacbbabab", "ababb", 2)`.

Comment: Another one: both `fuzzy_pberndt` and `fuzzy_nelxiost` fail on test case `('babaacb', 'abab', 2)`.

Comment: ... and a very simple one: `fuzzy_nelxiost` fails on test case `('babaa','aba',1)`

Comment: I also tested `fuzzy_j_random_hacker`: it fails the test case `('bacbcbaab', 'bcba', 1)`. Also `fuzzy_nelxiost` and `fuzzy_pberndt` fail that test.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Turns out my approach was entirely wrong - I'll replace it with the brute force one in the question - and Nelxiost's variant is incomplete. `fuzzy_j_random_hacker` had a bug, I've fixed it in https://repl.it/DYKl/8

Comment: Indeed, `fuzzy_pberndt` and `fuzzy_j_random_hacker` now seem to produce correct results. I optimised my code a bit for better performance. Among other things it has a short-cut for the case where the needle is a substring of haystack. If this test fails it can stop the algorithm as soon as a solution with 2 segments is found. I also removed the storage of the `next` node reference (which gave the "path" of the solution), since that info is not necessary for knowing the number of segments, and can still be derived in *O(n)* time, whenever the segments themselves need to be retrieved.

Comment: How are you doing with this question? Any further conclusions?

Comment: I haven't found the time to add Nelxiost's latest changes, but my guess is that your solution will still outperform the other one. I'm also waiting to see if FDavidov comes up with another solution. Having thought more about the problem myself, I'm starting to believe that one can't do much better than your solution though 

Comment: While there is no huge speed difference for the test cases from my Python script, the difference is pretty impressive for real-world data: Your solution requires about 2.2s on my system to crawl through 230.000 files from my home directory. My naive version needs about 20s for the same task. Nelxiost's can't compete with yours either. (Admittedly, my implementation of his algorithm is far from optimal though.)

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not the *most* efficient solution, but it is an efficient and easy to implement solution. To illustrate, I'll borrow your example. Let `/home/user/photos/2016/pyongyang_photo1.png` be the *filename*, and `ph2016png`, the *input*.

The first step (precalculation) is optional but might help speed up the next step (setup) quite a bit, especially if you are applying the algorithm to many filenames.

*Precalculation*
Create a table counting the occurrences of each character in the input. Since you are probably only dealing with ASCII characters, 256 entries are sufficient (maybe 128, or even less depending on the character set).

```
"ph2016png"
['p'] : 2
['h'] : 1
['2'] : 1
['0'] : 1
['b'] : 0
...
```

*Setup*
Slice the filename into substrings by throwing away characters that are not present in the input. At the same time, check if each character of the input is present the correct amount of times in the filename (if the precalculation is done). Finally, check that each character of the input appears in order in the substrings list. If you take the substrings list as a single string, for any given character of that string, every character that is found before it in the input must be found before it in that string. That can be done while creating the substrings.

```
"/home/user/photos/2016/pyongyang_photo1.png"
"h", "ph", "2016", "p", "ng", "ng", "ph", "1", "png"
'p' must come before "h", so throw this one away
"ph", "2016", "p", "ng", "ng", "ph", "1", "png"
```

*Core*
Match the longest substring with the input and keep track of the longest match. This match can keep the beginning of the substring (for instance, matching `ababa` (substring) with `babaa` (input) would result in `aba`, not `baba`) because it's easier to implement, although it doesn't have to. If you don't get a complete match, use the longest one to slice up the substring once more, and retry with the next longest substring.

```
Since there is no instance of incomplete match with your example,
let's take something else, made to illustrate the point.
Let's take "babaaababcb" as the filename, and "ababb" as input.
Substrings : "abaaabab", "b"
Longest substring : "abaaabab"

If you keep the beginning of matches
Longest match : "aba"
Slice "abaaabab" into "aba", "aabab"
-> "aba", "aabab", "b"
Retry with "aabab"
-> "aba", "a", "abab", "b"
Retry with "abab" (complete match)

Otherwise (harder to implement, not necessarily better performing, as shown in this example)
Longest match : "abab"
Slice "abaaabab" into "abaa", "abab"
-> "abaa", "abab", "b"
Retry with "abaa"
-> "aba", "a", "abab", "b"
Retry with "abab" (complete match)
```

If you do get a complete match, continue by slicing the input in two as well as the list of substrings, and repeat matching the longest substring.

```
With "ph2016png" as input
Longest substring : "2016"
Complete match
Match substrings "h", "ph" with input "ph"
Match substrings "p", "ng", "ng", "ph", "1", "png" with input "png"
```

You are guaranteed to find the sequence of substrings that contains the fewest substrings because you try the longest ones first. That will typically perform well if the input doesn't contain many short substrings from the filename.

Comment: Nice. I especially like the setup step. In my solution, one has to repetitively search for the next occurrence of the next character from the search string, raising the problem of how to store the result for the next lookup. By removing the unnecessary characters, you avoid having to search for characters entirely. [I hacked an implementation (without thinking too much of optimization) of this method](https://repl.it/DYKl/1), and its somewhere between 2x to 5x as fast as mine.

Comment: Looking at your code, I realized I forgot to add a part to the setup that actually uses the table of occurrences, instead of a table of presence (I edited). Also, I'm not good at Python, but I'm pretty sure there is an easy way to avoid regular expressions and increase performance.

Comment: @Philip, I tried the implementation you created for this, but get an assertion error on test case `("aba", "ab", 1)`.

Comment: @trincot Thanks! I didn't "keep track of the longest match" correctly. I've fixed this now, [but then I noticed I misunderstood something else](https://repl.it/DYKl/3). @Nelxiost: In your first example in the "Core" section, you'll eventually end up matching `['16', 'p', 'ng', 'ng', 'ph', '1']` against `61`. None of the 2-character strings match, so you check, find that `16` has the best match, split that into `1`/`6` and repeat. Since no 2-character string matches anymore, you retreat to the singles. But `1` now exists twice in the list. How do you decide which one to use without trying both?

Comment: @Phillip Well you try the first one and see if it works. You then end up trying to match `[]` to `"6"` and `['6', 'p', 'n', 'g', 'n', 'g', 'p', 'h', '1']` to `""`. So you throw that out and match `['6', 'p', 'n', 'g', 'n', 'g', 'p', 'h', '1']` to `"61"`.

Comment: Ah, I had hoped that there would be an alternative to backtracking. This makes the worst-case behavior of this algorithm considerably worse, right? [It's still the fastest one so far though.](https://repl.it/DYKl/6)

Comment: @Phillip There might be an alternative but I can't think of one. The worst-case behavior is bad indeed, but that's why it's called worst-case. After all, `"ph2061png"` only matches `"/home/user/photos/2016/pyongyang_photo1.png"` because of the extra `1` at the end (`1.png`).

Comment: @Nelxiost @trincot mentioned `('babaacb', 'abab', 2)` above in his answer. [Here's what happens](https://gist.github.com/phillipberndt/2fd22acf6daefc204eb3b5051358d778). Even if you resolve this using backtracking and retrying with another substring, this will eventually produce the wrong answer, because splitting `bab` from `aa` creates an artificial gap that isn't present in the best solution.

Comment: @Phillip The longest match isn't `"bab"` in that case, it's `"aba"`. You match the needle with the haystack, not the opposite. The needle needs to match from the beginning until one character doesn't match. Maybe I should've clarified that.

Comment: @Nelxiost In this case, I am afraid that I don't understand your example: If the needle needs to match from the beginning, then why does the longest haystack substring "2016" match the needle "ph2016png" in your example? (Or do you mean that when matching the longest of the haystack's substrings against the needle, you should try to find any substring of the needle in the haystack's substring, but preferably long ones starting at an early index of the needle?)

Comment: @Phillip Hm. That's embarrassing, I confused myself writing this last comment. I meant "you match the substring (of the haystack) with the needle, not the opposite". With the filename`babaacb` and the input `abab`, you have to match `babaa` with `abab`, and the result should be `bab` because you match from the beginning of the substring.

Comment: @Nelxiost That's what happens in [the above example](https://gist.github.com/phillipberndt/2fd22acf6daefc204eb3b5051358d778), isn't it? But there, splitting `babaa` into `bab` and `aa` leads to the described issue - namely that `aba` is never found, but would be the ideal match..

Comment: @Phillip You are right indeed, silly me. I guess the setup was incomplete ; I added a part to it. It should get rid of any problem of that kind and shouldn't impact the performance that much.

Comment: For the `ph2061png` needle, the haystack substring `2016` does not contain the needle characters in the correct order. Your description currently reads as if you'd suggest to drop the entire substring in this case. I think that your intention was to instead use the two substrings `20` and `6` in this case, right? At least, implemented like this, [the algorithm produces correct results for the test data](https://repl.it/DYKl/9).

Comment: @Phillip Good point, I forgot to update this part. I completely remade it because your base example doesn't illustrate the algorithm as I would have wanted it to. In the case of `ph2061png`, the substring `2016` is indeed incorrect, you would have split it in two by dropping this `1`.